# Configure IIS 5.1 for SMTP

Tags: iis, smtp

I've tried a number of solutions that I found on the internet, but none worked. I can telnet to port 25 and send an email via IIS 5.1 listening on that port, but the email never gets delivered. 
I see that all of the emails end up in : C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Drop\

My network setup is as follows:

```
a. It's a lan, with gateway 192.168.1.3
b. We use a broadband connection with Dynamic IP address to connect to the net
c. I do have a IP address for my website.
d. The Site is hosted on Yahoo. We use Yahoo Small Business Email
```

My question is: Is it possible at all to configure a SMTP on my local LAN, and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

If you're dead set on using IIS (and Magnetic_dud's right, there are far nicer solutions), you need to set the SMTP service up to relay correctly - you can either set it to try and deliver directly, using DNS to work out where to send mail for a particular domain, or forward everything on to an external smart host (mail relay) to deliver it for you - do Yahoo offer one of these as part of their Small Business email?

If you want to go for direct delivery, be aware that you'll need to have proper reverse DNS set up for whatever public IP your mail comes from, otherwise most receiving MTAs won't talk to you.  A lot of mail servers also won't accept connections from dynamic- or residential-looking IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [HMailServer](http://www.hmailserver.com/). It is much easier to manage and troubleshoot, and "cleaner" IMHO then MailEnable if you just want to do SMTP.

Comment: wow, hmailserver looks good! But it does not have a nice webmail like MailEnable. On the other side, support for clamwin and spamassassin are not on mailenable-free

Comment: Yes, I don't use it as a mail server, just as an SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try [MailEnable](http://www.mailenable.com/), it's free and WAY easier to configure compared to Microsoft's Mail Server